# Can I install iBitterlich forestry app on an iPhone 4S

Tags: iphone, internet

I would like to get an iPhone 4S to run [iBitterlich](http://www.taakkumn.com/taakkumnRoom/iBitterlich.html) but
don't want to get internet service for the iPhone. If I buy an iPhone 4S somewhere, can I download the app via wifi to my HP Pavillion 6 laptop (and it's internet), and run it without any internet service on the phone?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, although if you can connect your computer to wifi, it seems like you can connect your iPhone to wifi. The standard way to install apps on an iPhone is to connect it to wifi. However, assuming that isn't possible for you, it is easy to install via iTunes.

For more information:

- [Install Apps Via iTunes](https://www.google.com/search?q=install%20apps%20via%20itunes&es_th=1&rct=j)
- [OS X Daily Article](http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/16/remotely-install-apps-ios-from-computer/)

Comment: the wifi would have to originate from my laptop (at least that is how my computer talks to my printer); my only link to the internet is via a broadband modem.  I could download iTunes onto my laptop